# Loading data into BigQuery with api

Tags: api, google-bigquery, crm

How can I load data into BigQuery from CRM using its API every day in stated time?

I have pretty complex system to build: I need to collect data from Google Analytics, some connectorless services and CRM, the only possible way to interact with is via API.

The question is that possible to use an API request to get data and add it in the and of specified table everyday, for instance, like in Apipheny connector for Google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some information about setting up automatic Google Analytics exports to BigQuery, since you mentioned that first: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en

If you want to avoid building your own tooling from scratch, look at the Data Transfer Service (DTS). The purpose of DTS is to enable managed transfers automatically, and may be able to handle the other sources you alluded to in your question.

In addition to supporting transfers from other Google services, it enables third party transfers from a variety of sources. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/third-party-transfer to find out more.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I need. 
Btw, after some readings, if I write a Python script to get the data and push it to GBQ, does Google provide a service to save the script and run it when specified?

Comment: There's a variety of tools for this.  [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/) (managed airflow), [workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs), and [scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) are some that come to mind, though composer is probably overkill if it's just the one scheduled script.  Scheduler you'd likely want to pair with cloud functions or something similar as the place where the script is hosted.